# How I can get list of all classes from given bundle

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

I have an Eclipse bundle and want to get a list of all classes from this bundle.

**How can I do it?**

Comment: From JUnit Plug-in test, for example (not from Eclipse GUI interface).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the classes from the bundle will be in classNameOfCurrentBundle list in the end:

```
BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
// Getting all the class files (also from imported packages)
Collection<String> resources = bundleWiring.listResources("/", "*.class", BundleWiring.LISTRESOURCES_RECURSE);

List<String> classNamesOfCurrentBundle = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String resource : resources) {
    URL localResource = bundle.getEntry(resource);
    // Bundle.getEntry() returns null if the resource is not located in the specific bundle
    if (localResource != null) {
        String className = resource.replaceAll("/", ".");
        classNamesOfCurrentBundle.add(className);
    }
}
```

Converting the className to class type:

```
bundle.loadClass(className);
```

Comment: Please, see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895399/get-bundle-classes-of-private-packages-in-another-bundle