# Get bundle classes of private packages in another bundle

Tags: java, osgi

I have two osgi bundles A and B. All packages of bundle A are private. In bundle B I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800118/5057736:

BundleA

```
class ClassA extends ClassB{
    ClassA(){
      super(ClassA.class);
    }
}
```

Bundle B

```
class ClassB{
...
public void doFoo(){
{ 
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ClassAReference);  
BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
// Getting all the class files (also from imported packages)
Collection<String> resources = bundleWiring.listResources("/", "*.class", BundleWiring.LISTRESOURCES_RECURSE);

List<String> classNamesOfCurrentBundle = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String resource : resources) {
    URL localResource = bundle.getEntry(resource);
    // Bundle.getEntry() returns null if the resource is not located in the specific bundle
    if (localResource != null) {
        String className = resource.replaceAll("/", ".");
        classNamesOfCurrentBundle.add(className);
    }
}
```

However, I get resources - all classes which bundle A classloader loaded. But I need only the classes which are inside bundle A. I mean I need classes which belong to bundle A. To get them as I understand I need localResource. However,localResource is always null, but the classes are exactly in bundle A - for example ClassA . How to get classes which belong to bundle A in ClassB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Collection<String> resources = bundleWiring.listResources("/", "*.class", BundleWiring.LISTRESOURCES_RECURSE);
```

use

```
List<URL> resources = bundleWiring.findEntries("/", "*.class", BundleWiring.FINDENTRIES_RECURSE);
```

The second function only looks for resources in the specific bundle and in its fragment bundles. See the javadoc: https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWiring.html#findEntries(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: I think a more important question is: what on earth is @JimJim2000 actually trying to do??

Comment: Probably some bytecode manipulation, weaving and AOP. All the things that one should avoid in OSGi.

Comment: Well... other questions suggest he hasn't heard of services. From this question it sounds like he's using reflection to directly access classes from inside other bundles? I shudder to think.